# std::set of MyElement with MyElement::SomeMethod as custom comparator

Tags: c++, c++11, set, custom-compare

I have a simple `MyElement` class, and I would like to use a `bool MyElement::SomeMethod(...) {...}` as the custom comparator for a `std::set` of `MyElement` items.

I have made my research, and I am already aware of some alternative solutions, which I list below.
I also know how to change, for example, the comparator with `std::greater` instead of the default `std::less`, with code like this:

```
std::set<MyElement, std::greater<MyElement> > s;
```

My exact problem is that I want to use `bool MyElement::SomeMethod(...) {...}` as custom comparator.
The only solution I come up with is analogous to the last one in the list below, namely the solution for boolean function:

```
using Cmp = std::integral_constant<decltype(&MyElement::SomeMethod), 
                                   &MyElement::SomeMethod>;
std::set<MyElement, Cmp> my_set;
```

This solution only works for a `static` `MyElement::SomeMethod`, though.

I am wondering if there is an analgous, or more concise, way for a non static method.

List of alternative solutions:

**method for C++20**

```
auto cmp = [](const MyElement& lhs, const MyElement& rhs) { return ... };
std::set<MyElement, decltype(cmp)> s;
```

**method for C++11**

```
auto cmp = [](const MyElement& lhs, const MyElement& rhs) { return ... };
std::set<MyElement, decltype(cmp)> s(cmp);
```

**function instead of a lambda**

```
 bool cmp(const MyElement& lhs, const MyElement& rhs) { return ...; }
```

and then

```
std::set<MyElement, decltype(cmp)*> s(cmp);
```

or

```
std::set<int, decltype(&cmp)> s(&cmp);
```

**struct and operator()**

```
struct cmp {
    bool operator() (const MyElement& lhs, const MyElement& rhs) const {
        return ...
    }
};
```

and then

```
std::set<MyElement, cmp> s;
```

**boolean function**

```
bool cmp(const MyElement& lhs, const MyElement& rhs) {
    return ...;
}
```

and then

```
#include <type_traits>
using Cmp = std::integral_constant<decltype(&cmp), &cmp>;
std::set<MyElement, Cmp> s;
```

Comment: C++20 can also do `std::set<MyElement, decltype([](const MyElement& lhs, const MyElement& rhs) { return ... })> s;`

Comment: @Artyer thanks for the reminder, I am deciding whether to add it to my question or if it could make confusion :)

Comment: Is `MyElement::SomeMethod` static?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat no, it isn't.

Comment: Then the `integral_constant` trick doesn't work: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3e41zzsY4

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you! I talked too early because I compiled my example only declaring the set but not using it. I update my question.

Comment: Are you looking for `typedef std::function<bool(const MyElement&, const MyElement&)> comparer; std::set<MyElement,comparer>{comparer{&MyElement::SomeNonStaticMemberFunction}};` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks. To me (meaning my programming skill) this solution is a bit tricky. I think it's because of its two parameter signature. The first one is supposed to be ```this``` pointer, right? Because it only works if ```SomeNonStaticMemberFunction``` has one parameter.

Comment: @vaeVictis: Yes, the `std::function` constructor will turn a pointer-to-non-static-member-function into a callable whose first parameter is the target object, which is known as `this` inside that member function, and the remaining parameters of the callable match the real parameters of that member function.

Comment: @vaeVictis: If you intend for the comparator to accept both objects to be compared, you can use a lambda or `std::bind` to build the `std::function` bound to a particular target object.  But you asked specifically how to do it with a non-static member function, which means you want a `this` object somehow used in the comparison, and I'm confused how you will use it if it is not either of the two objects being compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::mem_fn` to bind a member function.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

struct S {
  int i;

  bool cmp(const S& other) const { return i < other.i; }
};

// Define make function to avoid having to write out template types.
template <typename T, typename Cmp>
std::set<T, Cmp> make_set(Cmp&& cmp) {
  return std::set<T, Cmp>{std::forward<Cmp>(cmp)};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto s = make_set<S>(std::mem_fn(&S::cmp));
  s.emplace(S{0});

  std::cout << s.begin()->i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for you, but my vote is locked. Please, just edit your answer so my vote could be shown. This being said, this solution works fine but I have just one question. Is it possible to use a two-parameter cmp? Something with ```lhs``` instead of ```this``` and ```rhs``` instead of ```other```.

Comment: @vaeVictis: You certainly can name the parameter `rhs` instead of `other`.  But I can't understand what a comparator should mean with three objects in play (`*this`, `lhs`, and `rhs`).  No, you cannot rename the `this` keyword, but you can alias it.  For example: `bool cmp(const S& rhs) const { const S& lhs = *this; return lhs.i < rhs.i; }`.   If you just want to have two parameters and no `this`, then use the `static` keyword.  But your question said you already could do it with a static member function and you specifically asked how to use a non-static member function (with a `this` pointer)

Comment: @BenVoigt my questions, badly written both here and under your other comment, was due to a little confusion with your solution function signature and Dev's one. I read some other documentation and I can say that you two have completely unraveled all my doubts. I appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit subjective, but to me the cleanest option is struct + operator() to match the definition of `std::less`, the default comparator for `std::set`. There's nothing wrong with the other options but a comparison functor is a common pattern and easy to recognize.

You could also define `MyElement::operator<`, and then you wouldn't need to pass in a comparator separately.

Comment: I agree, and I use this solution or a lambda. I am just exploring alternative ways.

Comment: Keep in mind readability. Most of those approaches aren't idiomatic and harder to read. That doesn't necessarily disqualify them, but styles that follow the common patterns of the language are easier for others to understand at a glance.