# std::unordered_set and alternative and overcomplicated ways of defining custom Hash and EqualKey

Tags: c++, c++11, hash, c++17, unordered-set

I am working with `std::unordered_set` of `CustomKey` objects and I am thinking about how to complicate my life.

I already know the idiomatic ways of using custom Hash and EqualKey. For custom Hash it's possible to implement a class that overrides the `operator()` or a custom specialization of `std::hash` (which could be also injected in the namespace std). For a custom EqualKey it's possible to implement a class that overrides the `operator()` or a specialization of `std::equal`, or an overload of `operator==()` of CustomKey.

I wrote that I complicate my life because I am exploring alternative ways for custom Hash and EqualKey, in the spirit of this [other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70525253/stdset-of-myelement-with-myelementsomemethod-as-custom-comparator)

I defined these three custom Hashes inside `CustomKey` class:

```
static size_t CustomKey::ClassStaticHash(const CustomKey& doubleStringKey) {...}
size_t CustomKey::ClassNonStaticHash() const {...}
class CustomKey::ClassClassHash
{
    public:
    size_t operator()(const CustomKey& myCustomKey) const {...}
};
```

and these three outside:

```
size_t CustomFunctionHash(const CustomKey& myCustomKey) {...}
auto CustomLambdaHash = [](const CustomKey& myCustomKey) {...};
class CustomClassHash
{   
    public:
    size_t operator()(const CustomKey& myCustomKey) const {...}
};
```

In a similar way, I defined these three custom EqualKeys inside `CustomKey` class

```
static bool CustomKey::ClassStaticEqual(CustomKey const& lhs, CustomKey const& rhs) {...}
bool CustomKey::ClassNonStaticEqual(const CustomKey& other) const {...}
class CustomKey::ClassClassEqual
{
    public:
    bool operator()(const CustomKey& lhs, const CustomKey& rhs) const {...}
};
```

and these three outside:

```
bool CustomFunctionEqual(const CustomKey& firstCustomKey, 
                         const CustomKey& secondCustomKey) {...}
auto CustomLambdaEqual = [](const CustomKey& firstCustomKey, 
                            const CustomKey& secondCustomKey) {...};
class CustomClassEqual
{
    public:
    bool operator()(const CustomKey& firstCustomKey, 
                    const CustomKey& secondCustomKey) const {...}
};
```

As for now, I managed to define an `unordered_set` for all the single custom Hash and for half of the 36 combinations of the 6 custom Hash and the 6 custom EqualKey.

Instead of providing a detailed list, which would be devastating for you to read, I opt for dividing all the cases in six sets, illustrate what I was able to do and ask what I had problem with.

So, let's go!

**First problem**

For what concerns `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticHash`, I defined two templates:

```
template <class T, class Hash>
std::unordered_set<T, Hash> make_unordered_set(Hash&& hash) 
{
    return std::unordered_set<T, Hash>{10, std::forward<Hash>(hash)};
}

template <class T, class Hash, class KeyEqual>
std::unordered_set<T, Hash, KeyEqual> make_unordered_set(Hash&& hash, KeyEqual&& keyequal) 
{
    return std::unordered_set<T, Hash, KeyEqual>{10, std::forward<Hash>(hash), std::forward<KeyEqual>(keyequal)};
}
```

and I can instantiate both an `unordered_set` with only `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticHash`

```
auto my_unordered_set = make_unordered_set<CustomKey>(std::mem_fn(&CustomKey::ClassNonStaticHash))
```

and an `unordered_set` with `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticHash` and `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticEqual`

```
auto my_unordered_set = make_unordered_set<CustomKey>(std::mem_fn(&CustomKey::ClassNonStaticHash), std::mem_fn(&CustomKey::ClassNonStaticEqual));
```

I have tried to implement other templates, but they did not work and **I don't understand how to instantiate** an `unordered_set` with the other combinations, namely with `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticHash` and respectively `CustomKey::ClassStaticEqual`, or `CustomKey::ClassClassEqual`, or `CustomFunctionEqual`, or `CustomLambdaEqual`, or `CustomClassEqual`

**Second problem**

For what concerns `CustomKey::ClassStaticHash`, I am able to define all but one `unordered_set`. For example, for the combination with `CustomLambdaEqual`,and similarly with all others but `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticEqual`, I have:

```
typedef std::function<size_t(const CustomKey&)> Hash;    
std::unordered_set<CustomKey, Hash, decltype(CustomLambdaEqual)> my_unordered_set{10, Hash(&CustomKey::ClassStaticHash), CustomLambdaEqual};
```

**The problem is with the combination** of `CustomKey::ClassStaticHash` and `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticEqual`. How could I instantiate an `unordered_set` with `CustomKey::ClassStaticHash` and `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticEqual`?

**Third problem**

For what concerns `CustomKey::ClassClassHash`, I can easily instantiate:

```
std::unordered_set<CustomKey, CustomKey::ClassClassHash> my_unordered_set;
```

I can also easily instantiate the combination of `CustomKey::ClassClassHash` and `CustomKey::ClassClassEqual`

```
std::unordered_set<CustomKey, CustomKey::ClassClassHash, CustomKey::ClassClassEqual> my_unordered_set;
```

and the combination of `CustomKey::ClassClassHash` and `CustomClassEqual`

```
std::unordered_set<CustomKey, CustomKey::ClassClassHash, CustomClassEqual> my_unordered_set;
```

**The problem is with the combinations** of `CustomKey::ClassClassHash` and respectively `CustomKey::ClassStaticEqual`, or `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticEqual`, or `CustomFunctionEqual` or `CustomLambdaEqual`. The main reason is that I don't understand how to specify `CustomKey::ClassClassHash` in the template parameters and the various EqualKeys in the parameter of the constructor.

**Fourth and fifth problem**

For what concerns `CustomFunctionHash` and `CustomLambdaHash`, the problem is very similar.

**In both cases I don't understand** how to instantiate `unordered_set` for the combination with `ClassNonStaticEqual`.

**Sixth problem**

For what concerns `CustomClassHash`, I can easily instantiate an `unodered_set` with `CustomKey::ClassClassEqual`

```
std::unordered_set<CustomKey, CustomClassHash, CustomKey::ClassClassEqual> my_unordered_set;
```

and with `CustomClassEqual`
std::unordered_set<CustomKey, CustomClassHash, CustomClassEqual> my_unordered_set;

**The problem, here, is with the combinations** with `CustomKey::ClassStaticEqual`, or `CustomKey::ClassNonStaticEqual`, or `CustomFunctionEqual` or `CustomLambdaEqual`. The main reason is similar to the third problem: I don't understand how to specify `CustomClassHash` in the template parameters and the various EqualKeys in the parameter of the constructor.

I repeat that I am aware that there are idiomatic ways to use unordered associative containers like `unordered_set`. The main reason why I am asking about these combinations is to ask for a feedback about how to play with templates.

I will truly appreciate every effort of those who will have the patience to read and help.

Comment: `CustomKey::ClassStaticHash` and `CustomKey::ClassStaticEqual` you should be able to just pass to `make_unordered_set` as is. What happens when you try? `CustomKey::ClassClassHash{}` and `CustomKey::ClassClassEqual{}` should work as-is, too.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z6PnxdvoP) of a few combinations. Trying all possible combinations is left as an exercise for the reader. The forms of `Hash` and `Equal` should be variable independently; I don't see how choice of one could restrict or dictate that of the other.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I thank you very much for taking the time to read my question and even write a demo. I will check it soon and give you a feedback! Thanks!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am back. I've tried all possible combinations and it works perfectly. I have just one question. What is the meaning of the curly braces any time you pass a class as an argument for ```make_unordered_set```? Is that just a normal initialization? This being said, if you feel like writing an answer, it will be my pleasure to mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes, it means "a default-constructed temporary of this class". You could use a pair of parentheses, too.